# Create One Pandas DataFrame From Multiple DataFrames Which Were Generated From Loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a loop that generates multiple dataframes using pandas, all with the same column names, but different data in each. These are all generated in the loop as such, the dataframe don't have a name so I can do the usual concat method of merging them all into one by name.

The loop is something like this.

```
df = pd.read_csv("dataframe.csv")

list_of_names = ["name1", "name2", name3] 

for name in list_of_names:
    df.loc[(df['Name'] == f'{name}'), 'New_Name'] = 1
    print(df)
```

This gives me something like:

```
Name  New_Name
Tom    1

Name  New_Name
John    1

Name  New_Name
Dave    1
```

i.e. multiple frames

But I want all that put into one frame.

Like so:

```
Name  New_Name
 Tom    1
 John   1
 Dave   1
```

I could do these one by one not in a loop, but the list of names of very long. This way I can add a new column called "New_Name" with a value of "1".

So, I now have a lot of seperate dataframes generated from that loop. How do I put them all into one dataframe.

Comment: If you are formulating multiple, dfs, you can just append them to a list and them concatenate them

Comment: Tried this already. Didn't seem to work.  I put this at the end. Sorry, it doens't ship properly in the comments                                                                      
        ```mylist = []
        mylist.append(df)
        df = pd.concat(mylist)
        print(df.head(5))``` it just gave me back what it always does. Multiple dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure i understood you correctly, but i think what you want is to create multiple df objects and them concatenate them into one single row. For that a simple, list filled with dataframe objects can do the tricks

Lets just say than in your sample, you gave me the condition to formulate the new dfs, although concatenate filtered dfs, is a little weird I am just gonna go with it

```
l_df = []
for name in list_of_names:
    l_df.append(df.loc[(df['column_name'] == f'{name}'), 'New_Name'] = 1)

pd.concat(l_df)
```